# Visual Studio 2017 - cannot compile newly created Asp.Net core 2.0 project using template API on a PC?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

I created a new Asp.Net core 2.0 project with API template using Visual Studio 2017 V15.7.3. However, the newly created project cannot be compiled and it got the following error.

However, I did the same on another machine and it compiles.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1202  Package System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates 4.1.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Net.Primitives 4.0.11 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Reflection.Metadata 1.3.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Reflection.Metadata 1.3.0 does not support any target frameworks.              
Error   NU1202  Package System.Threading.Timer 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Threading.Timer 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net451 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1)
  - portable-net451+win81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile151)
  - win81 (Windows,Version=v8.1)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Threading.Thread 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Collections.Concurrent 4.0.12 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Collections.Concurrent 4.0.12 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Diagnostics.Tracing 4.1.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.AppContext 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.AppContext 4.1.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - netstandard (.NETStandard,Version=v0.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Collections.Immutable 1.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Collections.Immutable 1.2.0 does not support any target frameworks.              
Error   NU1202  Package System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.11 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.11 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Security.Principal 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Security.Principal 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Security.Cryptography.Csp 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Diagnostics.Contracts 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Diagnostics.Contracts 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wp8 (WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.IO.Compression 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.IO.Compression 4.1.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Runtime.Loader 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Runtime.Loader 4.0.0 supports: net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2)                
Error   NU1202  Package System.Globalization.Calendars 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Globalization.Calendars 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Threading.Overlapped 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Threading.Overlapped 4.0.1 does not support any target frameworks.                
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Win32.Primitives 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.0.10 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Threading.ThreadPool 4.0.10 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.Win32.Registry 4.0.0 does not support any target frameworks.              
Error   NU1202  Package System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Xml.XPath 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow 4.6.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow 4.6.0 does not support any target frameworks.                
Error   NU1202  Package System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Diagnostics.Process 4.1.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Linq.Parallel 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Linq.Parallel 4.0.1 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - portable-net45+win8+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile111)
  - win8 (Windows,Version=v8.0)
  - wpa81 (WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Console 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Console 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.2.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.2.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Error   NU1202  Package System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo 4.0.0 supports:
  - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
  - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
  - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
  - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)             
Warning NU1701  Package 'System.Linq.Queryable 4.0.1' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. Watcher C:\Users\wangyi\source\repos\Strats\Watcher\Watcher.csproj  1   
Warning NU1701  Package 'System.Xml.XmlSerializer 4.0.11' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. Watcher C:\Users\wangyi\source\repos\Strats\Watcher\Watcher.csproj  1
```

Tried to reinstall VS 2017 and it stil have the same issue.

**Update: `dotnet new webapi` got the same errors**

```
PS C:\TEMP> dotnet new webapi
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.
This template contains technologies from parties other than Microsoft, see https://aka.ms/template-3pn for details.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj...
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202: Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.
NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Text.Encoding.CodePages 4.0.1 supports:
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - xamarinmac20 (Xamarin.Mac,Version=v2.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - xamarintvos10 (Xamarin.TVOS,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - xamarinwatchos10 (Xamarin.WatchOS,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202: Package System.Diagnostics.Contracts 4.0.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NE
TCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package System.Diagnostics.Contracts 4.0.1 supports:
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - monoandroid10 (MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - monotouch10 (MonoTouch,Version=v1.0)
C:\TEMP\TEMP.csproj : error NU1202:   - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure if you are still seeing the issue, but clearing the nuget cache resolved this for me. 
From Visual Studio you can [image: VS 2017 clear nuget cache]

or you can run

```
nuget locals all --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason NuGet is pulling .NET Framework packages. Ensure that the only referenced package is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`. If there are specific other packages that you actually intended to reference, ensure that those are actually compatible with .NET Core. If they require .NET Framework, NuGet's going to try to pull the .NET Framework specific packages, which won't work when targeting Core.

Comment: It happens even if I use the VS to open a compiled project which is newly created (without any change) by another Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes, it only refers to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.0.8)` under NuGet.

Comment: Just found that `dotnet new webapi` got the same errors.